# Giving my program 'options'

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, subclass, nsbutton

Ok,

In XCode 4 I have created 3 small programs: A calculator, a 'scratch pad' (blank note-type window), and 'spread sheet' (just looks like a spread sheet, for holding values gained with the calculator)

What I'm trying to do now is add a button to my calculator that will, when pressed, execute either the scratch pad or the spread sheet and give the user the option of which one to pick.

I've placed both the bundles in the 'applications' folder so they are easy to find.

I was wondering if I need to subclass an NSButton or if there is an easier way to do it.

I was thinking that I could just make the NSButton open a file-browser at /users/me/applications and then when the user (me :-) ) chooses one of the applications it will just store it as a variable that the button will then execute when I press it's key-equivalent.

But then I don't know how to give the button two different actions, a 'click' and a 'press'

If I have to subclass the button, where should I begin looking? And if there's an easier way, where would that be?

Comment: What do you mean by a “press”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the simple solution would be two buttons, one for each program.

If you're set on using just one button, then the straightforward thing to do is to have the button's action display a sheet or dialog box that lets the user decide which application to launch.

Comment: I'd like to to the second method (I'm using this application to learn the ins and outs of objective-c as a compliment to the apple documentation and their objective-c books).  I was wondering how I could let the button have 2 functions, one to select the program and another to actually launch it.  Is this possible with the standard NSButton or would it need to be subclassed?

Comment: I think the right way to do this, if you really want to use a single button, is to use NSPopupButton rather than NSButton. A click on a popup button reveals a menu. Your button could display a menu with the names of your two applications, and selecting an application from the menu would launch that app. This avoids the need for subclassing and provides a UI that should be familiar to users.

Comment: I like this approach, it sounds nice.  Is there any way to make it so that the menu allows me to decide which of the programs the button will run, and then pressing its 'keyboard equivalent' will actually launch the program?

Answer (score 2):

> I like this approach, it sounds nice. Is there any way to make it so that the menu allows me to decide which of the programs the button will run, and then pressing its 'keyboard equivalent' will actually launch the program? – TotalCocoaNewb

Certainly so:

```
-(IBAction)theActionYouSetOnThePopupButtonInInterfaceBuilder:(NSPopUpButton*)sender
{
    if ( 0 == [sender indexOfSelectedItem] ) {
       // do something...
    } else {
       // do something else...
    }
}
```